# can't run ember samples

Tags: ember.js

I've downloaded the samples for ember.js and when I run the basic todo sample I get the following errors.  The error sounds like one of the scripts aren't loading, but I've verified that all the files are loading correctly.  I can successfully run the exact same file from the emberjs.com web site, so I'm not sure what's going wrong.  Any ideas?

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Handlebars is not defined          ember.min.js:17
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'extend' of undefined        app.js:44
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure you've included Handlebars. Earlier versions of Ember came with Handlebars, but newer versions do not.

Just add something like this to your page (before you include Ember).

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/wycats/handlebars.js/handlebars-1.0.0.beta.6.js"></script>
```

Comment: Wow, you would think that the samples would have included that.  Thanks, that did it!